# speeding up as.POSIXct with large data / issue with storing as POSIXct in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, posixct

I am trying to extract a list of `POSIXct` login times from a large .csv (~11m rows), then use the `cut` function to tabulate the number of logins per 15-minute block.

Given the size of the dataset, I am using the `data.table` function. I have managed to achieve my objective, however I have run into some problems described below:

`#selective fread
dt <- fread("foo.csv", colClasses=list(NULL=c(1:5,8:14), "POSIXct"=c(5,6))  )`

*Issue: I tried to store the 2 relevant columns as POSIXct classes but it appears to be stored as a `character` class instead:*

`> class(dt$login_datetime)
[1] "character"`

I managed to run the rest of my code by using `as.POSIXct` as shown below:

`timeLog <- dt[,1, with=FALSE]
timeLog<- timeLog[,login_datetime:=as.POSIXct(login_datetime)]
tabulate <- data.frame(table(cut(timeLog, breaks="15 mins")))`

However, the second line takes about 12 minutes to run on my machine. I need to process more datasets in a similar fashion, and while 12 minutes is not devastatingly slow I am curious as to whether I can speed up this process (short of hardware upgrades).

Specifically, I tried to get `fread` to store the relevant columns as `POSIXct` classes directly and was unable to. I was unable to find anything regarding POSIXct in the [data.table vignette here](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro-vignette.html).

Would anyone be able to tell me if 1) I am doing something wrong regarding `fread` and `colClasses="POSIXct"`, or 2) if there are other ways/packages to speed up conversion of a `data.table` column to POSIXct?

Thanks.

Comment: See lubridate::lubridate with `options(lubridate.fasttime = TRUE)`

Comment: @bergant: that requires the [fasttime](http://www.rforge.net/fasttime/) package, which isn't on CRAN.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that. Is there any reason why `fasttime` isn't on CRAN? Compatibility issues etc, or is it just annoying to deal with CRAN's standards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest two options.

I assume you use `write.csv` or similar, which convert `POSIXct` to `character` when writing it out. This slows down both the writing out and reading in, as `POSIXct` object are really numbers and not characters (more precisely they are seconds since "epoch"). So you can convert the column to `numeric`, and then write that out, and convert back to `POSIXct` after reading in (which will be super fast).

Another option, if you prefer to write out character columns, is to use `fastPOSIXct` from `fasttime` to speed up the conversion to `POSIXct`.

Comment: By "I assume you use write.csv or similar", do you mean to say that the original .csv dataset was written using the `write.csv` command? 

As for your solution, are you saying I should read the data in as `colClasses=numeric`, and the conversion from `numeric` to `POSIXct` is faster?

Comment: Yes to first question. To second question I suggest writing out those columns in numeric format (which will require explicit conversion if you use `write.csv`, i.e. `foo[, numCol := as.numeric(posixCol)]` and then write that out) and then reading back in numeric format and converting back to posix (i.e. after reading in - `foo[, posixCol := as.POSIXct(numCol)]`).

Comment: Hmm well the dataset did not come from me and I do not have control over it. I guess I will have to try reading it in as `colClasses=numeric`, and failing that, look into `fasttime`.
 . . . . .. . . . .. . . . .. . . . .. . . .  . .  . . . . . .  . (trying to add a line break but unable to do so).     .    ..         .    ..    .   .     .    ..    .   ..   .     .    ..    .   .   .In any case, how is it different if the .csv is written as `numeric` or `character`? I thought that a .csv simply stores the data, ie it stores a "7" as a byte regardless of whether it was numeric or a character.

Comment: `colClasses=numeric` won't help unfortunately, since your file stores text, not a number, which brings us to second part: .csv files are simple text files, *not* binary files, so when you write the number `12345` in a csv file, it's written as text and so will use 5 bytes.

Comment: i see. since i can't control the way the .csv is written i guess my only option is to look at the `fasttime` package, or deal with the speed. thanks!